# Find the color of a pixel UNDER a semi-transparent window

Tags: c++, win32gui

I need to find the color of the background pixel UNDER the program window,
which is semi transparent.
Thanks,
alex

Comment: Did you try anything? How did you create the window? Give _details_.

Comment: I use [code] HDC hDC = ::GetDC(NULL);
 COLORREF cr = ::GetPixel(hDC, x+100, y+100);
 COLORREF cr1 = ::GetPixel(hDC, x-20, y-20); They both return the same value, so obviously something is wrong.

Comment: Asking a window for its colour is never going to give you the colour of the window underneath it, transparent or not. That's not how it works. You need to query the actual window whose colour you need...

Comment: That is so. There are two strange things though: 1. the color we get for both pixels is identical, although one of them is outside the window; 2. the color is not always the same, although the window color didn't change.